# How to convert JsonElement to a Int or other primitive types

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0, webapi, jsonconvert

I have c# webapi on .net 6.0. And I am getting postdata from client into param_class into _input. the class is like following:

```
public class param_class
{
    public string? name { get; set; }
    public object? value { get; set; }
}
```

client sends data as json string like following:

```
{
    "name": "lotnum",
    "value": 143
}
```

in webapi, when I get value field throws error JsonElement cannot convert to Int.

```
var v = (int)_input.value;
```

how to convert from JsonElement to other types in webapi of .net 6.0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change `value` type to `int` and default deserialization will handle this for you.

What is actually happening right now is when you have an `object` type for a property, it is `JsonElement` since this is the type that `JS` sends. But if you change it to the expected type, the default deserializer knows how to convert from `JsonElement` to the specific type you are expecting. (since `JsonElement` itself sends what type it is)

Of course, you have the option to post-cast it as follows:

```
var v = ((JsonElement)_input.value).GetInt32();
```

I *HARDLY* suggest you not do it!